# Picking up my daughter

Tags: verbs

In my note to the school should I write "I will pick up my daughter at 2:00," or "I will pick my daughter up..."?

Comment: Either is acceptable.

Comment: Phrasal verb!  If I'd only known... Thank you for your help. :)